# Android 2.3.3 rotating View

Tags: android, view, bitmap, rotation

I'm working on Android 2.3.3, I've created a class that inherit from View, and i need it to rotate.

As this image explains: http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/2464/boundedbox.png

Asi this example shows, I'm having trouble adjusting the bitmap rotation (inner rectangle) within the new area space. I need to get the X an Y from the bitmap.

Here's part of the code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {         
    matrix.setTranslate(x,y);
        matrix.setRotate(rotate);
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,matrix, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Please tell me if you need additional information,
Thank you!